# Minimize error in op.amps?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ac, error

How do i minimize error due to Offset voltage, Bias Current, Offset Voltage, 
Frequency response etc.
For an µa741.

I have no idea on how i can cancel or just minimize the effect of these errors.
I would be very glad if someone could help me :(.

I am actually using in a negative feedback circuit.. So as far as i Understand.. Bias current can be compensated by setting the impedance at the input to be the sane, any values preferable?.. Bias offset I won't  be able to change,minimize or compensate. Offset voltage same as bias offset... Frequensy response is just the fact that Aol chances in frequency..Could someone explain me about domaint poles and single poles, and what it has to do with frequency compensation and how it has something to do ringing with the op.amp and what it means.. ?

Comment: You could reduce all of those errors by simply using a different op-amp than the 741. If you tell us your real end goal, and the circuit you're using the op-amp in, maybe we can suggest the right part and/or improvements to the circuit.

Comment: Even if you have some wild reason you absolutely have to use a '741, at least share your circuit and application with us so we have some ideas which of those errors will most affect you.

Comment: If you want a certain frequency response, it's best to start with the right op-amp. The amount of dominant pole compensation limits the frequency response, and it is built into the op-amp; it cannot be reduced. Negative feedback flattens the frequency response, of course, but it doesn't extend the upper limit.

Comment: user25282: I believe the question in people's minds here is whether your question is from a purely hypothetical beginner standpoint, "Since the 741 has so many problems, how do people use it at all?", or whether the questions are around a practical issue or issues you are facing with something you have actually started to design or implement. Clarifying this in the question would help us out, both in answering, and in figuring out whether the question ought to be considered "too broad".

Comment: Asking about "dominant poles" and "single poles" and "ringing" is really asking about stability of op-amp circuits. That's really a whole different topic than offset voltage and bias current...Your edit has actually made the question broader rather than narrower.

Answer (score 1):

Negative feedback is needed for most regular op-amp circuits and this will stablize your the open-loop frequency resonse to the closed loop (and perfectly reasonably flat) frequency response. It will also provide just the right amount of dc voltage fed back so you are not fighting against offset voltages and currents. But what it won't do is minimize offsets and there will be a dc offset on your output representative of input offset x circuit gain.

The uA741, like a lot of op-amps, has pins where you can connect a potentiometer to correct offsets and they do a good job but, the real niggly offset errors related to temperature, cannot be nulled this way.

To reduce offset voltage, the most effective way is to get a better op-amp. There are complex methodss of doing it that involve using a 2nd op-amp but i'm not going to go into this because, for the vast majority of applications requiring better dc accuracy, it's better to get a better op-amp and, almost certainly, most op-amps are better than the ancient uA741.

Bias currents can be easily reduced with matching resistances in both inputs (the effect of the bias currents cancel out) but, offset currents are a bit trickier and the best way is by having small resistances for feedback and input connections. However, this isn't always convenient and so it's a trip down the shop for a better part.

[This](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/tutorials/MT-037.pdf) is a decent article about voltage offsets from Analog Devices - it's called **Op-amp input offset voltage (MT-037)**

MT-038 is a similar article about offset currents and here is a picture of an op-amp open loop response before (red) and after (blue) feedback has been applied: -

[image]

The frequency response is now essentially flat with a gain of about 20dB from DC to about 1MHz. It's not for a uA741 - it's representative of how feedback works.

Comment: The 741 has dedicated pins for nulling the offset voltage. These are easy to use. Just connect a 10K potentiometer across the pins, with the wiper to the negative rail. This basically shifts the balance of the collector currents in the differential input stage. It might round out the answer to include this.

Comment: @Kaz Ok, I didn't mention it because you can't do anything with temperature variations of Voi but I'll stick it in.

Comment: What makes you think OP is not already using a negative feedback circuit?

Comment: @ThePhoton I didn't want to assume he either was or even knew about it. He might be using an op-amp as a comparator and Ithought it best to steer the answer to using negative feedback.

Comment: I am actually using in a negative feedback circuit.. So as far as i Understand..

Bias current can be compensated by setting the impedance at the input to be the sane, any values preferable..

Bias offset won't i be able to change,minimize or compensate

Offset voltage same as bias offset...

Frequensy response is just the fact that Aol chances in frequency..Could someone explain me about domaint poles and single poles, and what it has to do with frequency compensation and how it has something to do ringing with the op.amp

Comment: @user25282 that is a big subject, probably alot bigger than offsets so maybe raise another question about it. Do you know about complex numbers or at least bode plots showing frequency responses with peaks. BTW a bode plot is really the last digram shown in my answer. BTW (again) single poles that affect non-zero frequencies always come in pairs. This now conjurs up the concept of negative frequencies. It's complex but if you raise the question I'm sure you'll get some really good answer because a lot of folk on this site know about this.

Comment: Bodeplots and complex numbers yes..

Comment: @user25282 I think the general concensus regarding this new topic (op-amp ringing/frequency compensation and pole-zero diagrams) is that you raise a new question else the question may become closed due to it covering too much unrelated subject matter. I know you don't think it is unrelated but going from DC control and simple frequency responses to the new stuff is a giant leap as they say!!